# How to debug Android App to grant privilege permission?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

I am new to Android development. My current task requires to grant "Capture_audio_output" runtime permission. Android Developer site describes the permission as "Not for use by third-party applications".

I learned from some answers that I can root my phone and install system app. But I don't want to do that way.

I also tried to generate a signed debug apk file, but the app didn't show up even ADB told me it was installed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

`CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT` is not a dangerous permission and so does not work with the runtime permission system. `CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT` has `android:protectionLevel="signature|privileged"`, so it can only be held by apps that are installed on the privileged (a.k.a., system) partition or are signed by the platform signing key.
Even if you create your release signed APK, still it will not get the privilege of getting this permission. Either you have to root your device or you can't get it.

Comment: Is there any other way to grant this privileged permission for our third party apps, without rooting?

Comment: @AmeenaShafeer no there is no direct or documented way of getting as per my knowledge. ther could be hacks but are not recommended because the variety of devices nowadays that you have to deal with are not easy to tackle.